# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined(…)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The issue appears to be:

```
$("#results").append("<div class='list-group'><a class='list-group-item' href='https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title.replace(" ", "_")) + "' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.bs-example-modal-lg'><h4>" + item.title.replace(" ", "_") + "</h4><p class='list-group-item-text'>" + item.snippet + "</p></a></div>");
```

And its call

```
page: e.relatedTarget.textContent,
```

> Hit the button Wikipedia, get the results, click on a result = should
>   load its wikipedia page: [JSFiddle playground](https://jsfiddle.net/kgyc8to4/51/)

The following has it:

```
$("#wiki").one('click', function(e) {
  var articleName = $(this).data('subject');
  $.getJSON("https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?", {
    srsearch: articleName,
    action: "query",
    list: "search",
    format: "json"
}, function(data) {
    $("#results ul").empty();
    $("#results ul").append("<h3>Results for <b>" + articleName + "</b></h3>").text();
    $.each(data.query.search, function(i, item) {
      $("#results").append("<div class='list-group'><a class='list-group-item' href='https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title.replace(" ", "_")) + "' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.bs-example-modal-lg'><h4>" + item.title.replace(" ", "_") + "</h4><p class='list-group-item-text'>" + item.snippet + "</p></a></div>");
      $("#results div a").attr("href", "#");
     });
     $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $.getJSON("https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&callback=?", {
            page: e.relatedTarget.textContent, 
            prop:"text"
        }, function(data) {
            $(".modal-content").html(data.parse.text['*']);
        });
     });
 });
});
```

While this works but I need the above one due to the html within it:

```
$("#wiki").one('click', function(e) {
  var articleName = $(this).data('subject');
  $.getJSON("https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?", {
    srsearch: articleName,
    action: "query",
    list: "search",
    format: "json"
}, function(data) {
    $("#results ul").empty();
    $("#results ul").append("<h3>Results for <b>" + articleName + "</b></h3>").text();
    $.each(data.query.search, function(i, item) {
      $("#results").append("<a class='list-group-item' href='https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title.replace(" ", "_")) + "' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.bs-example-modal-lg'><h4>" + item.title.replace(" ", "_") + "</h4><p class='list-group-item-text'>" + item.snippet + "</a>");
      $("#results div a").attr("href", "#");
     });
     $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $.getJSON("https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&callback=?", {
            page: e.relatedTarget.textContent, 
            prop:"text"
        }, function(data) {
            $(".modal-content").html(data.parse.text['*']);
        });
     });
 });
});
```

Comment: You're resetting the `<a href=>` to `#` two times over in these lines: `$('#results div a').attr('href','#');` - which means it's trying to fetch from `<a href="#">` instead of the link with the Wikipedia-article. Fix that first.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie thanks, fixed that. Yet the issue is stille there. Question and JSFdille updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `e.relatedTarget.textContent` is giving you the whole text - that is the title and the description. You need just the title for the search to find a result.

Take a look at the Network tab in dev tools and you will see that there is an error "The page you specified doesn't exist" in the response.

Change to pick out the h4 content only:

```
page: $(e.relatedTarget).find('h4').text(),
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfsL4a85/)